# Configuration database in drools

Tags: sql-server, database, drools

i have downloaded jboss application server 4.2.3 and it had been running. Based on the documentation that i red (guvnor-docs), there's a setting behind guvnor but unfortunately, when i open it with guvnor `http://localhost:8080/drools-guvnor/`, i don't find "repository configuration" in Administration menu. It really doubt me because actually i want to connect my database (SQL Server) with this jboss. Is there any settings that i've miss? Could you tell solution to solve my problem? I really appreciate if anyone could answer it sooner. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The repository configuration is available for GUVNOR 5.3 above version. i think your using 5.0 version. Can you check once..